# relative path not working even with __init__.py

Tags: python, import, package, python-import, importerror

I know that there are plenty of similar questions on stack overflow. But the common answer doesn't seem to be working for me.

I have a file structure like this

```
  proj/
       lib/
          __init__.py
          aa.py
          bb.py
          test/
               __init__.py
               aa_test.py
```

I figured that if I include the code in my test.py

```
import lib.aa
```

or

```
from lib import aa
```

I would be able to reference the modules in the `lib/` directory. But that did not work.

So I tried to add to path, and it adds it correctly:

```
os.environ["PATH"] += ":%s" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join("..",""))
print os.environ["PATH"]
```

but even now when I try the import statements above... I keep getting the error

```
ImportError: No module named aa
```

or

```
ImportError: Importing from non-package <Something...>
```

Is there something obvious I am missing?

Is there a way to check if I have configured my `__init__.py` files correctly, or to see my package hierarchy?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to update your [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path), which is where python looks for modules, as opposed to your system's path in the current environment, which is what [`os.environ["PATH"]`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.environ) is referring to.

Example:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(".."))
import aa
```

After doing this, you can use your functions in `aa` like this: `aa.myfunc()`

There's some more information in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6098238/775982) for [python: import a module from a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/python-import-a-module-from-a-folder)

Comment: What about IDE's?  They won't know about the modules being inserted dynamically like this. What a mess for `python` imports

Answer (score 3):

The lib directory needs to be in your python module search path, which isn't the same things as the search path used by your shell.

This will probably work for you:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(".."))
```

However, it is probably better to run your code from a context where the lib package is already on the path. Such as from the 'proj' directory.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems and here is my advice.

Instead of changing `sys.path`, better run your test.py from being in `proj` (i.e. project root) directory. This way project dir will automatically be in `sys.path` and you will be able to import `lib` package.

And use absolute imports.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the code that you're trying to import lib.aa from?  I'm guessing /proj/ is not your working directory and it would need to be as it's setup right now.  Instead of PATH, you would want to add your directory to PYTHONPATH so it appears in the search path for an import.  See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Also, please take a look at http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html  It strongly recommends you put an extra level of directory in place so instead of `lib.aa`, you would refer to it as `my_proj.lib.aa`.

Answer (score 0):

System PATH variable is not used by python import statement. It uses PYTHONPATH, but best way to add new directory to import search path is to modify sys.path.

If this does not help, add to the question your value of sys.path and value returned by os.getcwd().

Answer (score 0):

In Sublime Text 3, abspath it didn't work for me.
I use this instead in the top "__ init __.py" file

Hope it works for you.

```
from os.path import dirname
from sys import path

path.insert( 0 , dirname( __file__ ) ) ;

from test import aa_test
```