# Ubuntu does not find module directory containing __init__.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, module

I have a python project with the following structure:

```
/project
  /bin  
     executable      
  /app  
     __init__.py
     a.py
     b.py
     c.py
```

From within the `/project` directory I try to run the executable, which depends on modules in the `app` package:

`./bin/executable`

However, when I try this, python fails to find any modules defined in the app package, giving the `ImportError: No module named XYZ` error.

From what I understood, the presence of `__init__.py` in the `app` directory should mark it as a module?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427037/relative-path-not-working-even-with-init-py

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't. I shouldn't need to add a directory to path/pythonpath if that directory already has an `__init__.py' file inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following to your executable (before you try importing your app module):

```
import sys; print sys.path
...
import app
```

You'll see that the current working directory is not included in the path. I suggest you create a proper Python package by adding a `setup.py` file. You can then install your package and your executable should work just fine.

Here is a simple `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

config = {
    'name': 'app',
    'version': '0.1.0',
    'description': 'some app',
    'packages': find_packages(),
}

setup(**config)
```

I prefer to install into a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python setup.py install
./bin/executable
```

Now, if you deactivate that virtualenv and try running your executable again, you will get your original `ImportError`.

Take a few minutes and read through the [Python Packaging User Guide](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Also, you might want to use `python setup.py develop` instead of `python setup.py install`.